# How to handle the graph data when the graph component is called in loop using react-redux

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-native

I am displaying the graphs by getting data from API and then looping it. 
Now I have a button in each of the graph components. when I click on one of the buttons only that graph data need to change, but I am seeing all the graphs are getting the change because of same reducers data is taking by graphs.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/TGjVW.jpg

In the above graph image, you can see if we click on week link in one of the graphs only that graph data need to change but both the graphs data are getting change.

> dashboard.js

```js
<Col md="12" lg="12" className="mb-3">
    {this.state.graphdata.map((data, i) => {
        return (
            <Col
                sm="12"
                md="6"
                lg="6"
                className="flt-lft pl-1 pr-1"
                key={i}
            >
                <Electricity
                    graphinfo={data}
                    loading={this.props.GraphDataRequest}
                    grapherror={this.props.GraphDataError}
                    daytypeinfo={this.graphchange}
                    pidinfo={this.state.locationid}
                    size={"12"}
                    location={"LOCATION"}
                />
            </Col>
        )
    })
</Col>
```

> Electricty.js

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
import Chart from "react-apexcharts";
import LineGraph from "./LineGraph";
import BarGraph from "./BarGraph";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { dashboardGraphDays } from "../../Actions";
class Electricity extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            optionsMixedChart1: {
                chart: {
                    height: 300,
                    toolbar: {
                        show: false
                    }
                },
                legend: {
                    position: "top",
                    fontSize: "26px"
                },
                dataLabels: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                tooltip: {
                    followCursor: false,
                    x: {
                        show: false
                    }
                },
                labels: [],
                xaxis: {
                    type: "month",
                    title: {
                        text: "hour"
                    },
                    labels: {
                        style: {
                            fontSize: this.props.size,
                            cssClass: "apexcharts-xaxis-label"
                        }
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    title: {
                        text: "Kwh"
                    }
                }
            },
            series: []
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.setState(prevState => ({
            ...prevState,
            optionsMixedChart1: {
                ...prevState.optionsMixedChart1,
                labels: this.props.graphinfo.labels,
                xaxis: {
                    ...prevState.optionsMixedChart1.xaxis,
                    title: {
                        ...prevState.optionsMixedChart1.xaxis.title,
                        text: this.props.graphinfo.xAxis.text
                            ? this.props.graphinfo.xAxis.text
                            : ""
                    }
                },
                yaxis: {
                    ...prevState.optionsMixedChart1.yaxis,
                    title: {
                        ...prevState.optionsMixedChart1.yaxis.title,
                        text: this.props.graphinfo.yAxis.text
                            ? this.props.graphinfo.yAxis.text
                            : ""
                    }
                }
            },
            series: this.props.graphinfo.series,
            header: this.props.graphinfo.header ? this.props.graphinfo.header : "",
            uidetailid: this.props.graphinfo.uiDetailId
                ? this.props.graphinfo.uiDetailId
                : "",
            location: this.props.location
        }));
    }

    componentDidUpdate(PrevPros, PrevState) {
        if (PrevPros.GraphDataSuccess != this.props.GraphDataSuccess) {
            this.setState(
                prevState => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    optionsMixedChart1: {
                        ...prevState.optionsMixedChart1,
                        labels: this.props.GraphDataSuccess[0].labels,
                        xaxis: {
                            ...prevState.optionsMixedChart1.xaxis,
                            title: {
                                ...prevState.optionsMixedChart1.xaxis.title,
                                text: this.props.GraphDataSuccess[0].xAxis.text
                                    ? this.props.GraphDataSuccess[0].xAxis.text
                                    : ""
                            }
                        },
                        yaxis: {
                            ...prevState.optionsMixedChart1.yaxis,
                            title: {
                                ...prevState.optionsMixedChart1.yaxis.title,
                                text: this.props.GraphDataSuccess[0].yAxis.text
                                    ? this.props.GraphDataSuccess[0].yAxis.text
                                    : ""
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    series: this.props.GraphDataSuccess[0].series
                }),
                console.log(this.state)
            );
            this.setState({
                header: this.props.GraphDataSuccess[0].header
                    ? this.props.GraphDataSuccess[0].header
                    : "",
                uidetailid: this.props.GraphDataSuccess[0].uiDetailId
                    ? this.props.GraphDataSuccess[0].uiDetailId
                    : ""
            });
        }
    }

    changeColor = Selecteddaytype => {
        this.setState({ selectedtype: Selecteddaytype });
        const consumptiontaginfo = consumptiondaytag();
        consumptiontaginfo.propertyId = this.props.pidinfo;
        consumptiontaginfo.interval = Selecteddaytype;
        consumptiontaginfo.uiDetailId = this.state.uidetailid;
        consumptiontaginfo.labelName = this.state.location;
        this.props.dashboardGraphDays(consumptiontaginfo);
    };

    showhidegraph = data => {
        data == "bar"
            ? this.setState({
                shown: true
            })
            : this.setState({
                shown: false
            });
    };
    renderData = () => {
        if (this.props.grapherror == "invalid data") {
            return <Error />;
        } else {
            if (
                this.state.optionsMixedChart1 &&
                this.state.optionsMixedChart1.length !== 0
            ) {
                return (
                    <Card className="mb-3 energy-cons-graph">
                        <CardHeader className="card-header-tab p-4">
                            <div className="card-header-title text-capitalize">
                                {this.state.header}
                            </div>
                            <div className="btn-actions-pane-right text-capitalize actions-icon-btn">
                                <div className="btn-group dropdown">
                                    <button
                                        className="btn-danger btn btn-shadow mr-1"
                                        onClick={() => this.showhidegraph("bar")}
                                        title="bar graph"
                                    >
                                        <i className="fa fa-bar-chart" aria-hidden="true" />
                                    </button>
                                    <button
                                        className="btn btn-success btn-shadow mr-1"
                                        onClick={() => this.showhidegraph("line")}
                                        title="line graph"
                                    >
                                        <i className="fa fa-line-chart" aria-hidden="true" />
                                    </button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </CardHeader>
                        <CardBody className="p-1 text-left">
                            <Button
                                color="link"
                                style={{ color: this.state.dailycolor }}
                                onClick={() => this.changeColor("DAILY")}
                            >
                                Daily
                                              </Button>
                            <Button
                                color="link"
                                style={{ color: this.state.weeklycolor }}
                                onClick={() => this.changeColor("WEEKLY")}
                            >
                                Weekly
                                              </Button>
                            <Button
                                color="link"
                                style={{ color: this.state.monthlycolor }}
                                onClick={() => this.changeColor("MONTHLY")}
                            >
                                Monthly
                                              </Button>
                        </CardBody>
                        <CardBody className="pt-0">
                            {this.state.shown ? (
                                <BarGraph
                                    options={this.state.optionsMixedChart1}
                                    series={this.state.series}
                                />
                            ) : (
                                    <LineGraph
                                        options={this.state.optionsMixedChart1}
                                        series={this.state.series}
                                    />
                                )}
                        </CardBody>
                    </Card>
                );
            } else {
                return <NoDataFound />;
            }
        }
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <Fragment>
                {this.state.loading == true ? <Loading /> : this.renderData()}
            </Fragment>
        );
    }
}
const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        GraphDataRequest: state.DashboardTable.MixedgraphdayFetching,
        GraphDataSuccess: state.DashboardTable.ResponsedayGraph.responseData,
        GraphDataError: state.DashboardTable.ResponsedayGraphError
    };
};
export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { dashboardGraphDays }
)(Electricity);
```